# Import all files from directory and map file name into array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I currently have this set up with Vue and Webpack:

```
const imports = {
  foo: require('./folder/foo.yml'),
  bar: require('./folder/bar.yml')
}
```

Is there a way to add more keys + values with this structure dynamically, where the key equals the file name without the file extension?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build such an object, example :

```js
var require = n => n;
var imports = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat'].reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = require(`./folder/${val}`);
 return acc;
}, {})

console.log(imports);
```

The values in the array could come from something like [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options), so we would have for instance :

```
const ymlFiles = fs.readdirSync('./folder')
  .filter(filename => filename.split('.').reverse()[0] === 'yml');
const ymlFilesNoExt = ymlFiles.map(filename => filename.replace(/\.yml$/, ""))
const imports = ymlFilesNoExtvar require = n => n;
var imports = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat'].reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = require(`./folder/${val}`);
 return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this helps.

```
const testFolder = './tests/';
const fs = require('fs');

const imports = {}

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    const filekey = file.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
    imports[filekey] = require('./tests/' + file);
  });
```